# Signed response after unsigned request with UserNameOverTransport

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, ws-security

I have to send an unsigned request with UserNameOverTransport. This part works as required.

Problem is the signed response. The mustUnderstand attribute is not set. So it is not required to validate the signature. Still the error I get is:

```
Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.
```

I would like to either validate the signature or ignore it. Just no exception.

My Binding:

```
<binding name="MvpBinding">
          <security includeTimestamp="false"
                    authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                    defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256"
                    requireDerivedKeys="false"
                    allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"></textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" />
        </binding>
```

The soap header:

```
<soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:kd4="http://www.ibm.com/KD4Soap">
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-f2d068c8-87de-4dd0-9a3a-f11ce53d444b" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsu:Created>2014-09-05T08:47:50Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2014-09-05T08:52:50Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-4e7c6de0-007d-4afc-9e28-c68de09368a6" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">MIIE6zCCA9OgAwIBAgISESHYLw+ktfA+n3/v0Gmcvus...kf2qLDNUcKvLpW6pu11nFInk4P6ITfpzFvbwYLzwdEXpTr+Tp6FZEwRlOkfZqvFwCu/McnMebVWwB4RD+YdxLpJQz9kxivvLaNtHUkObNmkrtcGlJiLLaxyWron56+hEVNFqumhqBMIOfUHYCMlKkW1lmvxheHWTTz8uCpBYCEQvs7B2zsyqw</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#Timestamp-f2d068c8-87de-4dd0-9a3a-f11ce53d444b">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>zhzUEkYsK3HdX+J8/0Bv+By1W/A=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#Body-493e1e76-a11f-4c9c-8ef9-7231ff86354d">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>o0j1TY3Zd8mfs59Z4K2Vrlu9seQ=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
               <SignatureValue>...geofKdEYJH/TbpXjO8w==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns="">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-4e7c6de0-007d-4afc-9e28-c68de09368a6" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for it? I have very same problem :-/

Comment: No a solution that fits exactly my question. Asymetric security protocols afaik cannot be configured with WCF My solution was that the server accepts a signed request. So both request and response are signed.